# Proving divergence of the fraction of the square root - without using proof by contradiction

Tags: sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta, divergent-series

I need to solve the following question:

Prove using $\varepsilon$ and N that the following sequence is divergent:
$$a_n = \sqrt{n} - ⌊\sqrt{n}⌋$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n) \ne L$$

**Without using proof by contradiction** -

which means I need to show that for any $L\in \mathbb{R}$ exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for any $N\in \mathbb{N}$ exists n such that $n>N \,$ and $\, |a_n-L| \ge \varepsilon$.

I've tried to split it into $L\le 0$ and $0<L\le 1$ and $L>1$

or $L\le 0 $ and $L>0$ - but nothing helped...

Answer (score 2):

What can you say about $a_{k^2}$ and $a_{k^2 - 1}$ as $k$ ranges through the positive integers?  What's the limit of their difference?

Comment: ohh i see it now - if we take $n=k^2$ i get $a_k^2 = 0$ and i can get the $l\ne0$ part and the limit of their difference is zero i guess?

Comment: @hihi : Certainly, $a_{k^2} = 0$.  But $a_{k^2 - 1}$ leaves a large fractional part (in fact the largest of any $n$ in $[(k-1)^2, k^2 - 1]$).  These fractional parts increases as $k$ increases, so for any $\varepsilon \in [0,1)$, there is a $k$ for which $|a_{k^2} - a_{k^2 - 1}| > \varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding two subsequences that converge to two different numbers.

Check these limits.

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \,(\sqrt {n^2} - n) = 0$$

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \big(\,\sqrt {(n^2-1)} - (n-1)\,\big) = 1$$